# Understanding and solving this eigenvalue problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the function $W(x)$ and the eigenvalue problem
$$
\Delta W+k^2W=0,~~~~~n\cdot\nabla W=0\text{ on }\partial\Omega.
$$

1.) Why is this called an eigenvalue problem?

2.) Solve this for $\Omega=(0,a), a>0$.

**My ideas**

1.)I think it is called eigenvalue problem since if we write it as
$$
\Delta W(x)=-k^2W(x)
$$
we see that the Laplace-operator maps $W(x)$ onto some multiple of it.

2.) I think, here we have
$$
\Delta W(x)=\frac{\partial^2 W(x)}{\partial^2 x}-k^2W(x)=0
$$
since we are in one dimension. But how can we solve this? Does it make sense to write it as
$$
\frac{d}{dx}W(x)=V(x),\qquad \frac{d}{dx}V(x)=-k^2W(x)?
$$

Comment: 1) Don't forget to add that Laplace operator is linear operator 2) It's just a homogeneous linear differential equation of second order. You just have to find its corresponding characteristic equation, find its roots and write solution as linear composition of exponents or sines/cosines or polynomials. It still makes sense to write it as you've written it, but this case doesn't require intricate analysis on phase plane. Also, don't forget about boundary conditions.

Comment: Hint, something is wrong here $$
\Delta W(x)=\frac{\partial^2 W(x)}{\partial^2 x}-k^2W(x)=0
$$

Comment: @Evgeny The corresponding characteristic equation is $m^2+k^2m=0$ with solutions $m_1=0$ and $m_2=-k^2$, hence $W(x)=c_1+c_2\cdot e^{-k^2x}$. Is that correct?

Comment: See @Michael 's answer.

Comment: I changed the sign, getting $W(x)=c_1+c_2e^{-k^2x}$.

Comment: Remember that function $W(x)$ is its zero derivative (=no derivation has been made). Because of that characteristic equation should be $m^2+k^2 = 0$, not $m^2 + k^2m = 0$ :)

Comment: Then, I get $W(x)=c_1\sin(kx)+c_2\cos(kx)$ and $W'(x)=c_1k\cos(kx)-c_2k\sin(kx)$. Setting $W'(0)=c_1k=0$ yields $c_1=0$. Setting $W'(a)=-c_2k\sin(ka)=0$ then should give $c_2$?

Comment: In order to solve $W'(a)=-c_2k\sin(ka)=0$, we have to possibilities: either $c_2=0$ or $k\sin(ka)=0$. I guess we do not want to have $c_2=0$, since then we would have $W(x)=0$. So we consider the second case, getting $k=0$ or $k=(n\pi)/a$. Again, I guess, we do not want to use $k=0$. Hence, all together, it remains: $W(x)=c_2\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{a})$.

Answer (score 0):

In an eigenvalue problem, the equation only has a nonzero solution for some values of $k$.  The simplest you know of is the matrix equation $Av=kv$, which has a solution $v=0$ for all $k$, but only nonzero eigenvectors for a few $k$.
You have changed the sign of $k^2$ in your working.
The boundary condition is that the first derivative is zero on the boundaries $x=0$ and $x=a$.